# After Submit for review can we have TestFlight working

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, testflight

I never tried this case, but this is sensitive for us, i just want to know that can we have `Testflight` working while app is in waiting for review or in review status?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible.

At the time it is sent for review, the current version is no longer available on testflight, have to upload a new one for testing, while the other is in review.